# When using Entity Framework with LinqPad or EFProviderWrapperToolkit, table valued functions have an incorrect SQL parameter type

Tags: .net, entity-framework, linqpad

My Entity Framework application uses several table-valued-functions to do full-text searches in SQL Server 2008.

My function parameters are always `strings` that translate to `nvarchar(4000)` in the store side. Everything works fine.

However, whenever I call the same functions from inside `LinqPad` or using a custom EF provider, specifically [EFProviderWrapperToolkit](http://code.msdn.microsoft.com/EFProviderWrappers-c0b88f32/sourcecode?fileId=19054&pathId=791898583), the string parameters are passed in as `nvarchar(1)` which stops them from working.

I'm specially concerned about the EFProviderWrapperToolkit because I wan't it to be used as my log layer.

Is there any way I can work around this?

I'm using `EF 4.2 2012 June CTP`, if you think that upgrading to `5.0` will help, I can give it a try. I did not yet because I think upgrading to `5.0` will force me to upgrade to `.NET 4.5 and VS 2012` which will cause a huge impact now as my product is in production.

**EDIT**

I just checked and the string parameters have been automatically imported this way:

```
<Parameter Name="aProcessoSimplesTerm" Type="nvarchar" Mode="In" />
```

You see that there's no size specification. I didn't change it, it is the way it has been imported.

Comment: V.5 works with .net 4 but not all new features will be operational. You could at least upgrade to the latest v.4 RTM, 4.3, although I don't think it solves your issue.

Comment: @GertArnold thanks for your response. Eh I may try that, but I don't think it will solve as well.. =/